# Pandas: Type conversion using `df.loc` from datetime64 to int

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, type-conversion

When trying to re-assign certain values in a column using `df.loc[]` I am getting a strange type conversion error converting datetimes to integers.

**Minimal Example:**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime
d = pd.DataFrame(zip(['12/6/2015', np.nan], [1, 2]), columns=list('ab'))
print(d)
d.loc[pd.notnull(d.a), 'a'] = d.a[pd.notnull(d.a)].apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime(2015,12,6))
print(d)
```

**Full Example:**

Here is my dataframe (contains NaNs):

```
>>> df.head()

  prior_ea_date quarter
0    12/31/2015      Q2
1    12/31/2015      Q3
2    12/31/2015      Q3
3    12/31/2015      Q3
4    12/31/2015      Q2

>>> df.prior_ea_date

0         12/31/2015
1         12/31/2015
...
341486     1/19/2016
341487      1/6/2016
Name: prior_ea_date, dtype: object
```

I want to run the following line of code:

```
df.loc[pd.notnull(df.prior_ea_date), 'prior_ea_date'] = df.prior_ea_date[pd.notnull(df.prior_ea_date)].apply(dt, usa=True)
```

where `dt` is a string to datetime parser, which when run normally gives:

```
>>> df.prior_ea_date[pd.notnull(df.prior_ea_date)].apply(dt, usa=True).head()

0   2015-12-31
1   2015-12-31
2   2015-12-31
3   2015-12-31
4   2015-12-31
Name: prior_ea_date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

However, when I run the `.loc[]` I get the following:

```
>>> df.loc[pd.notnull(df.prior_ea_date), 'prior_ea_date'] = df.prior_ea_date[pd.notnull(df.prior_ea_date)].apply(dt, usa=True)
>>> df.head()

         prior_ea_date quarter
0  1451520000000000000      Q2
1  1451520000000000000      Q3
2  1451520000000000000      Q3
3  1451520000000000000      Q3
4  1451520000000000000      Q2
```

and it has converted my datetime objects to integers.

- **Why is this happening?**
- **How do I avoid this behavior?**

I have managed to build a temporary work around, so I while any one-line hacks would be appreciated, I would like a pandas style solution.

Thanks.

Comment: what is `dt` in `apply(dt)`?

Comment: `dt` is a string-to-date parser, but this is not where the problem is coming from, as demonstrated by the minimal working example where I use the `datetime.datetime` function.

Comment: do you know what `1451520000000000000` even is?  And how to get that value from `'2015-12-31'`?

Comment: @piRSquared, `1451520000000000000` is the time since epoch in nanoseconds of `2015-12-31`, which for python I think defaults to 01/01/1970. This can be seen via: `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1451520000000000000.0/1e9)` which equals `datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 31, 0, 0)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We'll start with the first question: **how to avoid this behavior?**

My understanding is that you want to convert the `prior_eta_date` column to datetime objects. The Pandas style approach is to use `to_datetime`:

```
df.prior_ea_date = pd.to_datetime(df.prior_ea_date, format='%m/%d/%Y')
df.prior_ea_date

0   2015-12-31
1   2015-12-31
2   2015-12-31
3   2015-12-31
4   2015-12-31
5          NaT
Name: prior_ea_date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Your first question is more interesting: **why is this happening?**

What I think is happening is that when you use `df.loc[pd.notnull(df.prior_ea_date), 'prior_ea_date'] = ....` you are setting values on a slice of the `prior_ea_date` column instead of overwriting the whole column. In this case, Pandas performs and tacit type cast to convert the right hand side to the type of the of the original `prior_ea_date` column. Notice that those long integers are epoch times for the wanted dates.

We can see this with your minimal example:

```
##
# Example of type casting on slice
##

d = pd.DataFrame(zip(['12/6/2015', np.nan], [1, 2]), columns=list('ab'))

# Column-a is still dtype: object
d.a
0    12/6/2015
1          NaN
Name: a, dtype: object

d.loc[pd.notnull(d.a), 'a'] = d.a[pd.notnull(d.a)].apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime(2015,12,6))

# Column-a is still dtype: object
d.a
0    1449360000000000000
1                    NaN
Name: a, dtype: object

##
# Example of overwriting whole column
##

d = pd.DataFrame(zip(['12/6/2015', np.nan], [1, 2]), columns=list('ab'))
d.a = pd.to_datetime(d.a, format='%m/%d/%Y')

# Column-a dtype is now datetime
d.a
0   2015-12-06
1          NaT
Name: a, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

**FURTHER DETAILS:**

In response to the OP's request for more under-the-hood details, I traced the call stack in Pycharm to learn what is going on. The TLDR answer is: ultimately, the unexpected behavior of casting `datetime` dtypes into integers is due to Numpy's internal behavior.

```
d = np.datetime64('2015-12-30T16:00:00.000000000-0800')
d.astype(np.dtype(object))
#>>> 1451520000000000000L
```

*...could you elaborate on why this type casting is happening when using .loc and how to avoid it...*

The intuition in my original answer is correct. It is due to the fact that the datetime objects are being cast into generic `object` types. This is because setting on the `loc` slice preserves the dtype of the column having the values set.

When setting values with `loc`, Pandas uses the `_LocationIndexer` in the [`indexing` module](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/1f883121c47940cf51fd33f40e64d18908153c71/pandas/core/indexing.py). After great deal of checking dimensions and conditions, the line `self.obj._data = self.obj._data.setitem(indexer, value)` actually sets the new values.

Stepping into that line, we find that the moment the datetimes are cast into integers, [line 742 `pandas.core.internals.py`](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/ce61b3f1c85c1541cfbe1b3bb594431b38689946/pandas/core/internals.py):

```
values[indexer] = value
```

In this statement, `values` is a Numpy `ndarray` of object dtypes. This is the data from the left-hand-side of original assignment. It contains the date strings. The `indexer` is just a tuple. And `value` is an `ndarray` of Numpy `datetime64` objects.

This operation uses Numpy's own `setitem` methods, which fills individual "cells" with calls to `np.asarray(value, self.dtype)`. In your case, `self.dtype` is the type of the left-hand-side:`object` and the value parameters are in the individual datetimes.

```
np.asarray(d, np.dtype(object))
#>>> array(1451520000000000000L, dtype=object)
```

*...and how to avoid it...*
Don't use `loc`. Overwrite the whole column as in my example above.

*...I thought having the column with dtype=object would avoid pandas assuming the object type. And either way it seems unexpected to me why it should be converting it to an int when the original column contains strings and NaNs.*

Ultimately, the behavior is due to how Numpy implements casting from from datetime to object. Now why does Numpy do it that way? I don't know. That is a good new question and a whole other rabbit hole.

Comment: Thanks for the `pd.to_datetime()` pointer. Otherwise could you elaborate on why this type casting is happening when using `.loc` and how to avoid it, as I thought having the column with `dtype=object` would avoid pandas assuming the object type. And either way it seems unexpected to me why it should be converting it to an `int` when the original column contains `strings` and `NaN`s.